# "A user access token is required to request this resource." Facebook graph for notifications

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

NOTE: When the user accepts my permissions to use my app. I ask them to accept `manage_notifications`

I am so confused. I research this on the web and it seems I get a mix of deprecated and wrong information and I am trying to send a notification to the user using my facebook canvas app using facebook graph. the following is how I do it and its not working.

```
public function getAccessToken() {
    $app_id = $this->settings['app_id'];
    $app_secrete = $this->settings['app_secrete'];
    $url =  "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?".
            "client_id={$app_id}".
            "&client_secret={$app_secrete}".
            "&grant_type=client_credentials";
    $c = curl_init($url);
    // necessary so CURL doesn't dump the results on your page
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($c);
    $result = explode("=", $result);
    curl_close ($c);
    return $result[1];
}
```

The result passes something like this  `access_token=523216317ewwer235|K4A1XugBpajwrweu1K2k12jzckdU` . so that is why i explode the `=` sign within the code. I call this function every time the user enters my app. I take the access code and pass it as `$token` in the following code.

```
public function alertUser($userid,$token,$message="You have a notification") {
    $inviteMessage = $message;
    $inviteMessage = urlencode($inviteMessage);
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$userid}/notifications?access_token={$token}&".
    "template={$inviteMessage}&ref=notify";
    $c = curl_init($url);
    // necessary so CURL doesn't dump the results on your page
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close ($c);        
    $r = json_decode($result);
}
```

and I get the following response

```
object(stdClass) {
    error => object(stdClass) {
        message => 'A user access token is required to request this resource.'
        type => 'OAuthException'
        code => (int) 102
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use POST requests in order to make notifications work :

`curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);`

Apparently you are making GET requests, trying to request a resource.

Comment: I think you might be right. I am guessing I have to set the params as postData too. i will give it a try and update the post. for my code has changes alot in the last hour.