# Facebook cannot send notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The user is logged in successful via fosfacebookbundle in symfony2.1

Related to this topic: ["A user access token is required to request this resource." Facebook graph for notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043512/a-user-access-token-is-required-to-request-this-resource-facebook-graph-for-n)

I want to send a notification to a user. The access token looks like this `...234|asdf...`.

```
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=
                     client_credentials&client_id=' . $app_id . '&
                     client_secret=' . $app_secret;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
//After that I do a preg_split. Or for testing I print out the access token 
  and I define it manual in the php file `$access_token = '...234|asdf...';`

$userid = 12345;
$inviteMessage = 'Test_message';
$inviteMessage = urlencode($inviteMessage);
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $userid . "/notifications?access_token=" . 
                $access_token . "&template=" . $inviteMessage;
$c = curl_init($url);
// necessary so CURL doesn't dump the results on your page
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
$r = json_decode($result);
print_r($r);
```

print_r gives me this: Sorry, something went wrong! Facebook Inc.

If I am directly put this in the address line:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/12345/notifications?access_token=access_token=...234|asdf...&template=Test_message
```

Error message:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token signature.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
}

What is wrong?

**Update**
What is the meaning of href in developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications?

Comment: Have you used the access token linter to be sure the access token is fine? As the error is complaining about the token.

Comment: Sorry, what is linter? I have never heard about it.

Comment: It is a tool that Facebook provides to debug access tokens: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/lint

Comment: Okay, when I type in my `https://graph.face...` the error message "Facebook URLs aren't scrapable by this Debugger. Try your own." comes up. What is the meaning?

Comment: That tool just takes the `access_token` not the entire url.

Comment: This looks fine. Even if I go to the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ I can see my correct access token. I don't need any permissions to send notifications, am I?

Comment: What is the meanding of href in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/?